# Implementing computation on a TCP based game application

Tags: sockets, tcp, architecture

We are planning a real-time network game application for mobiles.
After some researches and studying, we decided to use a TCP connection between the server and the clients (mobile devices) by implementing `Socket`.
As we are writing the protocols, we came across the following question: where should we implement the computation? In the user's device or in the server?

For example, imagine a short game between 5 players which does not require communication until the game ends (hitting the screen as fast as you can or something like that).
At the end of the round, the clients send their score to the server, and the application should display the loser or the winner.

Where should the computation take place? Should the server collect all of the scores, compute the maximum and the minimum and send back the loser and winner? Or should the server send back all the scores to the players, in which their devices will compute the results?
What are the pros and cons of each strategy?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here:

1)  Do not use a persistent socket for mobile applications.  Connectivity is too spotty.

2)  Use a higher level protocol, like HTTP.  You have no need to use such a low-level protocol.  By doing so you are going to end up doing far more work than you need to.  Think about if you want to build this into a web-based game, or implement on a device that doesn't allow you to use raw sockets.

HTTP is nice because it is firewall friendly, most firewalls already let HTTP on standard ports through.  This is why it is so popular these days.

3) You should think very skeptically about the devices.  In general you should trust clients as little as possible.  You can do processing on the client, but it should be related to rendering.  Generally assuming that your client is malicious is a good approach to n-tier architecture applications.  Especially with games.

Comment: What do you mean by "too spotty" ?  I need to use socket to be able to push messaged from the clients to the server, how can I achieve that using HTTP?

Comment: HTTP POST:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)  Take a look at http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069

Comment: I have mistakenly wrote from client to server, I meant to push from the server to the client. I know that websocket can achieve that, but it manages only 1 connection

Comment: Ok, I stick with my assertion that you should not trust the clients.  I also would at least think about still using HTTP, a polling paradigm works almost as well as server-push, and has the added benefit of being able to scale much higher.  (It's easy to run out of sockets on a server, but modern HTTP servers can service thousands of clients).